# Form settings validation (application and form name uniqueness)

Tags: orbeon

From the Orbeon [documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/form-editor):

> **Application Name.** Each form definition has an application name which identifies a group of forms that belong together. In practice, an application name might correspond to a project, or a department, or a company. For example, all forms built by Orbeon have the "orbeon" application name.
> NOTE: Depending on your permissions, the application name might have been picked for you already, or you might have the choice of a restricted set of application names.

> **Form Name.** Each form definition also has a form name, which identifies a unique form name within a particular application.

As orbeon's persistence API retrieves the form definitions by their application and form name, I would like to put some validation to the form settings page that would prevent the user to save a second from definition with the same application and form name as an existing one.

(My first approach would be to put some custom response to the persistence layer, but orbeon is not able to make difference between a general persistence error and a validation errror there with other words the backpropagation of the errors of the persistence layer/api to the user is not that mature, so to say.)

So how should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like Form Builder users to be prevented from creating a new form with an app/form name that is already used. The user could either be prevented from creating that form, or at least offered the option of opening the existing form instead of creating a new one with the same app/form name.

One question would be what, in that context, "already used" means: are we talking about forms editable by that user in Form Builder, or published forms? Maybe Form Builder should check both.

This check should happen in 3 places in Form Builder:

1. When the form is initially created (better warn users as soon as possible).
2. When users open the form settings dialogue to rename the form.
3. When saving (even if we're sure no form with the same app/name existed at the time the form was created, in the meantime another form with the same app/name might have been created).

In situation number one, if a form with the same app/name exists in Form Builder, Form Builder should provide the user the option to open that form instead of creating a new form.

So this is a feature that should be implemented at the level of Form Builder; it cannot be done solely by a custom implementation of the persistence API. This is covered by request for enhancement [#818](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/818).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I would like to cover the 2nd situation as I already covered the rest: the users are not able to import or copy an existing form def by defining app and formname of an already existed form definition. So that part is the last one that I should handle somehow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would make sense, but would really be something that needs to be implemented in Form Builder. Are you using Orbeon Forms CE or PE? If Orbeon Forms CE, would you have the time and interest to implement this on your side? -Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, we switched to PE about 2-3 months ago. But if it would not be too much effort, I would like to implement it because I don't have too much time for the task. AFAIK there is an xml-like structure that defines that form and maybe I could put there some custom javascript that would call something in my persistence layer, at least this would be my first approach. Hm?

Comment: Implementing is likely to be more involved than you think, especially if you are not already familiar with the technologies used by Orbeon Forms, like XForms, which doesn't bode well with "not having too much time for the task" ;). Alternatively, does your organization already have Dev Support with Orbeon? If so, they could sponsor that implementation using that Dev Support.

Comment: I will bring this up tomorrow and ask the right guy about this, thanks for the idea. Albeit  I feel the force to accomplish it with some guidance ;)